# DBCC CHECKCONSTRAINTS alternative in SQL Azure

Tags: azure-sql-database

Is there an alternative to DBCC CHECKCONSTRAINTS on SQL Azure? I can imagine, for instance, writing a sproc that enumerates all constraints and generates dynamic SQL to test them (such as "**`select t1.* from table1 t1 left outer join table2 t2 on t2.[key] = t1.[foreign_key] where t2.[key] is null`**") - has anyone already built something like this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Easiest method to resolve this would be to upgrade your server to v12 where we support DBCC CHECKCONSTRAINTS.

Comment: Fair enough - I will accept this as an answer if no one comes forth with the script I was looking for. Note that we cannot currently convert to V12 because we have too many Business/Web-tier databases. However, since those will be deprecated shortly, we will have to switch to the new tiers anyway.